# (integer) index of slice as array of structures

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, slice

Is it possible in Go create array with where each element of array will  be array of slices or structures.

Something like in PHP

```
    $a = [1=>"test", 2=>""]
    // in this example 2 is integer will be for GoLang?
    $a[2] = [ object, object, object ]
```

Can I do in Go something like ? I know about incorrect syntax.

```
   var a [int][]StructureName

   b := make([]StructureName, 0)
   b := append ( b, StructureName{a, b, c, d})
   b := append ( b, StructureName{e, f, g, h})

   a[0] = append (a[0][0], b)

`/*
[
1 => [
    ‘username1’, <-- string element
    ‘events’=>[ <-- array of structures
        object1, <-- structure
        object2, <-- structure
        object3 <-- structure
        ]
    ],
2 => [ <-- next record
    ‘username2’,
    ‘events’=>[
        object1,
        object2,
        object3
        ]
    ]
]
*/
`
```

Comment: Can you be more clear ? Do you want to create Array of Arrays ?

Comment: I need create array with first element with username and second element with array of structures ( records with events for this username )

Aha and I need 1 more array where all of this arrays will be included
So, yes, it will be array of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map and map it from int => interface{}.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := make(map[int]interface{})
    var x []interface{}
    x = append(x, "username")
    x = append(x, []int{3, 1, 3})
    m[1] = x
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/B_dsvARic8c

Hope this helps.

Comment: After that can I create array of interface? Right?

Comment: Check the updated answer and go through the code in the link

Comment: @DmytroKravchenko yes you can

Comment: That is great answer =) Tnx.

Comment: When you know your fields i would opt for ThunderCats solution as interface{} could add a lot of hassle

Answer (score 2):

Declare types that match the structure of the data.  This ensures type safety and avoids the need to type assert when accessing the data.

In this case, it looks like you need a slice of structs where on of the fields is also a slice of event structs.

```
type Event struct {
    // Even fields TBD
}

type User struct {
    Name string
    Events []*Event
}

var users []*User

users = append(users, &User{
    Name: "name1",
    Events: []*Event{ object1, object2, object3 },
})
```

Comment: Why are you using var users  []*User instead of var users []User same with []*Event. Just for my personal interest as I'm learning go!

Comment: I think he is using because of safety issue. It is a pointers.

Comment: It could go either way. There's insufficient information in the question to know what's best.   Given that User has a slice member,  `[]*User` is probably a better choice than `[]User`.  Write the code both ways to see why.   We know nothing about the `Event` type.